# Have astronauts in space suits ever taken selfies? If so, how?

Tags: astronauts, photography, space-art, astronaut-lifestyle

Have astronauts in space suits ever taken selfies?

Were selfie sticks used?

If not, how was this feat accomplished?

Comment: Does this very famous Apollo 11 [image](https://history.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/AS11-40-5903HR.jpg) count as selfie? "No other Apollo photograph has been reproduced as often as this portrait of Buzz. Neil is, of course, visible in reflection on Buzz's visor."

Comment: @Uwe Is not Neil's pic a ["eifles"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_image)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Several space selfies were made](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_selfie) and chances are you already know the very first one [Buzz Aldrin took of himself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_selfie#/media/File:Buzz_Aldrin_self-photograph_during_Gemini_12_EVA_(S66-62926).jpg) during [Gemini 12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemini_12).

[image: Buzz Aldrin selfie during Gemini 12]

The cameras used are large-ish but imagine even holding a shoe box in front of you with thick gloves on: you're still able to point it at yourself in a distance suitable to make a photograph of yourself, provided the lens' focal length/field of view allows to capture enough of your face.

At least some of the cameras just look like a normal DSLR in a special casing and can be seen in the helmet reflections like this one:

[image: Luca Parmitano selfie]

There is a nice [gallery of space selfies at Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Space_selfies).

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about any of these, or that there was a selfie page. I'd assumed that astronaut cameras were set up to work only in the most conventional *point and shoot* configuration.

Comment: I've always assumed that selfies had to be done with smartphones, because the term includes a pun on the beginning of the word "cellphone". But I've checked a number of dictionaries and they just say that they're typically taken with a hand-held digital camera.

Comment: It's too bad the Apollo 12 crew couldn't get their smuggled self-timer to work.  The planned portrait of the two of them standing next to Surveyor III could well have beaten Armstrong's portrait of Aldrin as "most-reproduced".

Comment: The Apollo astronauts used a custom Hasselblad 500 EL.

Comment: @Barmar That only works in American English. Otherwise they're called "mobile phones". "self" plus a suffix "-ie" works in all varieties of English.

Comment: @CJDennis I guess they should be called "phonies" in other dialects :)

Comment: @DarkDust the question [Why ISS Astronauts have red stripes?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34622/12102) asks why stripes are red. Photos there and at [How do ISS astronauts “get their stripes”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34615/12102) and answers therein all show red stripes. But does your last image show a green stripe? If so, you may be able to add information on one or both of those.

Comment: @uhoh: Good catch! But that's a part of the [Italian flag on his shoulder](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:ISS-36_EVA-2_v_Luca_Parmitano.jpg) ^_^

Comment: @DarkDust Ah, so it is! I see, the next color (behind the green) is white, and easy to miss against the white of the space suit. **update:** There it is!  https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gBab.jpg